# How to add an if-clause using $scope derived from AngularJS in JSON-data?

Tags: angularjs, json, if-statement

Being a newbie in AngularJS and JSON, I have the following JSON-code:

```
{
    key: 'EI',
    value: 'Eingepasst',
    rate: Settings.get('partnerRate'), 
    variants:
    [
        { key: 'E0', value: 'Regulär', multiplier: 1, rate: Settings.get('partnerRate') }
    ]
},
```

However it should only be "used" in case a specific variable in AngularJS-code (to be detailed `$.scope.something`) gets a specific value.

How can I add such an if-clause herein (if possible)?

Comment: What do you mean by "it should only be 'used'...". Do you mean you want to prevent it from showing in html?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Does my reply help to better understand my issue and in case would it be possible to try an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if in your html where you are binding your json data.

So let's say you have a div that is bound to some of the properties on your model, you can wrap that all in a div that has ng-if on it as follows:

```
<div ng-if="something === expectedValue">
    <div>{{obj.rate}}</div>
    <div>{{obj.value}}</div>
</div>
```

This is a pretty primitive example, but if you have "something" defined on your $scope it should work.